# Should I post my comments as Answers?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I posted a comment something like "What you are trying to do, won't work and pointed to an answer to solve the problem" for [Question - 1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/144875/20830).

Both OP and @Rao, suggested to me post the comment as answer.

Since it points to another user's answer, shouldn't it stay as comment instead of an answer ?

Also I think he's pointing this question too:

[Question - 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/144690/20830) where I explain other user participated in the discussion was right by explaining what is happening.

What should I do for the above question too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eh I think you should follow your own instincts. If you have found a different question on SFSE that answers the question, neither course of action is as good as voting to close and linking to that duplicate. I'm not sure about Question 2, but I don't see what you're referring to in that case.

Comment: So shall I mark the question as duplicate?. Regarding the second question, if you could see there's an discussion why the order of console is different.To agree with Roa's logic, I posted a comment which explains what's really happening.Do you think, it should be posted as answer? I think Rao was referring it when he mentioned you are posting good answers as comments all over.

Comment: You should definitely mark the question as a duplicate. You can feel free to add an answer that indicates that this is a solved problem, and include the relevant aspects of the existing answer in addition to a link.

Comment: I really thank you for taking time to reply for the question and will keep in mind the things you said. Thank you again.